# Can you add items to a bound checkedListBox?

Tags: c#, linq, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox in a WinForms app, that are bound to a LINQ query.
Is it possible to add new items in the checkedListBox?  I would like to add the items to the list box and then have a user confirmation before committing them to the DB.
I guess I can have an unbound listbox with items from the DB, but was hoping for a quicker way.

I'm trying:

```
var avail = from c in dc.CostCenters
            select new { Item = c.CostCenterID, 
                         Description = c.CostCenterID + ": " + c.Description };
myList.DataSource = avail;
myList.DisplayMember = "Description";

myList.Items.Add(123, "New Description");
myList.Refresh();
```

It compiles and runs, but nothing is added in the list box control.

Comment: you can try to add items to data source directly

Comment: I thought that might be the way to go, but I would like to add the data in memory and then have the user confirm before committing it to the DB.  I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: @user1208908 you could try having a list of unconfirmed items and then adding `.Union(unconfirmedList.Select(unconfirmed => new { Item = unconfirmed.Value, Description = unconfirmed.Text })` to your query.

Comment: What data access technology are you using - with something like EF or most ERM's, updating the database is a separate step so you should be able to make this work.

Comment: using SQL with access through the LINQ to SQL DataContext (generated by sqlmetal)